# Bootstrap buttons Not rendering correctly for some users

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

[image]
Looks Like this. I can't seem to find a pattern. Most of the clients buttons are showing up correctly. But a select few are having this issue? I can't seem to find anyone else on the web that has had this issue before.

Comment: what do you mean by select few? Are those guys all using the same browser for instance? . Also please post some html & css code of the buttons.

Comment: I've seen it happen on chrome and ie10 so far. Chrome was probably a couple versions back, but I think it should still render correctly.

Comment: Do you have custom css? If you remove it, does the issue remains?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to use this CSS property.

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
```

Comment: Where do i put this on the button class?

Comment: `button, input, .btn, a.btn { -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; text-rendering: optimizelegibility; color: white; }`